# What is the record for most consecutive shots made to start NBA finals?

Tags: basketball, nba, postseason

Shaun Livingston of the Golden State Warriors started the 2017 - 2018 NBA finals with 11 straight field goals. His first miss came in the first half of the third game of the finals against the Cleveland Cavaliers.

What is the record for the most consecutive made baskets to start the NBA finals?